# Kounias' Inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, notation

Excercise 37 of One Thousand Excercises in Probability is to prove Kounias' Inequality:

$$P\left(\bigcup_{r=1}^n A_r\right)\leq\min_{k}\left\{\sum_{r=1}^nP(A_r)-\sum_{r:r\neq k}P(A_r\cap A_k)\right\}.$$

Kounia's original [article](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-39/issue-6/Bounds-for-the-Probability-of-a-Union-with-Applications/10.1214/aoms/1177698049.full) states that the upper for $P\left(\bigcup_{r=1}^n A_r\right)$ is

$$\min\left\{\sum_{i=1}^nP_i-\max_{k=1,2,\cdots,n}\sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^nP_{k,i},1\right\}.$$

What is the relation between $\sum_{r:r\neq k}P(A_r\cap A_k)$ and $\max_{k=1,2,\cdots,n}\sum_{i=1,i\neq k}^nP_{k,i},1$?